# Several CollisionShape2D for a AnimatedSpriteFrame

Tags: godot

I want to use CollisionPolygon2D for AnimatedSprite to attach to each frame perfectly but I can't do it.
Is there a way to define a unique CollisionPolygon2D for each frame?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AnimatedSprite` node is only concerned with graphics. And you would need the `CollisionPolygon2D` as children of a physics object (e.g. `KinematicBody2D`). Thus, you need something else to orquestarte them.

You may, for example, have multiple `CollisionPolygon2D`, one per `AnimatedSprite` frame. Have them all disabled, and in the `_process` of the physics object, you can enable only the one for the current frame:

```
var prior_frame:int = 0

func _process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var sprite:AnimatedSprite = $AnimatedSprite

    # make sure the collision for the current frame is not disabled
    var curr_collision := get_node(str("Coll", sprite.frame)) as CollisionPolygon2D
    curr_collision.disabled = false

    # if the frame is the same we last seen, we are done
    if prior_frame == sprite.frame:
        return
    
    # the frame is different, thus disable the collision for the prior frame
    var old_collision := get_node(str("Coll", prior_frame)) as CollisionPolygon2D
    old_collision.disabled = true

    # keep track of the frame we have seen
    prior_frame = sprite.frame
```

The above code assume that you have nodes called `Coll0`, `Coll1`, `Coll2` and so on. One per frame of the `AnimatedSprite`.

Comment: That's what I wanted.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AnimationPlayer` node. You can then set any parameter of your `CollisionShape`.

To do this:

- Select the `AnimationPlayer` node.
- Select the `CollisionShape` node.
- In the inspector tab you can now see a little key next to the properties.
- Select shape to see the collision shape.
- Now click the key next to shape and the name of the property.
- In your animation in the `AnimationPlayer` node, there is little diamond around the timeline.
- Move around the animation and change the properties to the desired values.

Comment: It's pretty hard to change `CollisionPolygon2D` at the exact time at which the frame changes in `AnimatedSprite`.
I think a better way exists. 
Anyway thanks for your kindness.