# Collisions on an animated sprite where the body moves around

Tags: godot

I have an animated sprite where the body of a projectile changes shape and size.  But I only have one CollisionShape2D.  I'm curious how to navigate this problem.  What I would kind of like is a CollisionShape2D per frame of the animation.  Is there a mechanism for linking changes to the CollisionShape2D with where we are in an animation?

I'm unsure of what to try here actually.

Comment: I think you should use a `AnimationPlayer` instead of an `AnimatedSprite` and within that animationPlayer you can change your sprite and the shape of the `CollisionShape2D` based on whatever the shape and size of the projectile is per frame

Comment: @cak3_lover You can use an `AnimationPlayer` *in addition of* an `AnimatedSprite`, and have the `AnimationPlayer` start the animation in the `AnimatedSprite`. That way the work done to make the animations in the `AnimatedSprite` is not lost. *Sadly the argument is often framed as "should I use a or b".*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Several CollisionShape2D for a AnimatedSpriteFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851722/several-collisionshape2d-for-a-animatedspriteframe)